# Can you prevent upscaling when using Craft's image transforms?

Tags: image-transforms

With [Craft's image transforms](https://craftcms.com/docs/image-transforms) used to resize images or generate thumbnails, can you prevent images from being *upscaled*? There's often cases where it makes no sense to *increase* the dimensions of an image.

It would be great if there was a setting for this, but I can't find one documented.

Otherwise, is the solution to fetch the image size in Twig and then *conditionally* apply the image transform?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As found [here](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/844), this actually seems to be a requested feature that is not yet implemented. However, in the link given, Brandon also supplied a workaround for the time being:

```
{% set transform = {
width: min(150, image.width),
height: min(100, image.height)
} %}

<img src="{{ image.getUrl(transform) }}">
```

Answer (score 4):

As of Craft 3.4 you can set `upscaleImages` to false in general config: https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/config-settings.html#upscaleimages

Answer (score 2):

If you want to work with transforms you've created in the backend you can use this:

```
{% set transformDimensions = craft.app.assetTransforms.getTransformByHandle('contentWidth') %}
{% set transform = {
    width: min(transformDimensions.width, image.width),
    mode: 'fit'
} %}

<img src="{{ image.url(transform) }}" alt="" />
```